# How to use strings as an ordering sequence?

Tags: python, string

I'd like to know how I can use a string like `order = '8927391'` (with 8 being largest and 1 being smallest) and print out an answer according to the order, for example:
Let's say `if_no_is_higher(no1, no2)` is a function that I have defined already to print `yes` if the first number is higher than the second, and `no` if the first number is smaller.

```
if_no_is_higher(8, 9)
```

returns

```
yes
```

because according to the order `8` is higher than `9`

Comment: What does that string have to do with a function that takes 2 arguments?

Comment: Try comparing the index of those numbers in the string

Comment: How do you go about comparing 2 and 9? You have 9 both before and after 2! And please provide a sample of your code. Not just a name of a desired function.

Comment: `for i in (int(ch) for ch in order):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom order and use the index of that collection to check for your condition:

```
a = '8927391'
custom_order = [int(item) for item in a]
min(8, 9, key=custom_order.index)
```